# Как подключить js код на вордпрес

Tags: wordpress

Всем привет, нужно добавить на сайт вот эту фишку:https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/deliveryCalculator .
Какими способами это возможно сделать? Буду очень благодарен за помощь

Comment: Какую именно "фишку" Вы хотите добавить? Что Вы сделали для этого и что именно не получилось?

Comment: я не особо знаю как добавлять код js и html, пробывал разместить код в заголовке, также привязывал апи яндекса. Хочу добавить карту с маршрутом и расчетом стоимости поездки

Comment: @Никита рекомендую вам ознакомиться с справкой сайта - категорией "как задать хороший вопрос", там как раз описано про теги для `js` и `html` кода..

Comment: а где её можно найти?)

Answer (score 0):

js-скрипты в ВП подключаются с помощью `wp_enqueue_script`
Напр

```
wp_enqueue_script('newscript', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/custom_script.js');
```

См подробнее:
https://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_enqueue_script
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script

Чтобы реализовать задуманное нужно [написать плагин](https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0) (предпочтительнее) или закодить непосредственно в теме.

Comment: а код нужно загружать на сервер или где-то его вставить?